# Solution to Discrete Log as a Commitment

Tags: discrete-logarithm, commitments

Is the solution to a discrete logarithm a reasonable commitment scheme?

By my analysis, the following scheme is a reasonable commitment scheme:
Let $p$ and $q$ be large primes such that $q∣(p−1)$, let $g$ be a generator of the order-$q$ subgroup of $Z^*_P$. Let $m$ be a value from $Z_q$, and $c=g^m\text{ mod }p$. The commitment is $c$ and to open the commitment, the sender reveals $m$.

I believe this scheme is:

- (Perfectly?) binding: The discrete logarithm only has one solution and so the sender can't reveal another value, $m'$, such that $c= g^{m'}\text{ mod }p$
- (Computationally?) hiding: Obviously, this scheme is not perfectly hiding. But assuming the discrete logarithm is hard, receiver or an adversary can't determine the committed message prior to reveal, so I believe this provides computational hiding.

Is my analysis of the binding & hiding properties correct? Are there other flaws not captured by hiding and binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously, this scheme is not perfectly hiding. But assuming the discrete logarithm is hard, receiver or an adversary can't determine the committed message prior to reveal, so I believe this provides computational hiding.

If the receiver had no other information about $m$, then you would be correct.

On the other hand, we typically assume that he has some information; the acid test is "if the receiver knew the committed value was either $m_0$ or $m_1$, he still cannot determine which it is from the commitment".

Obviously, your approach (or, for that matter, any deterministic method) cannot fulfill that requirement; you need to include some randomness to meet this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

and, if I'm not wrong, a possible way to add the randomness proposed by @poncho leads you to Pedersen commitments... which, by the way, have reversed properties strengths: theoretically hiding (thanks to introduced randomness) and computationally binding (because finding two couples $(randomness_{0}$,$m_{0})$ and $(randomness_{1}$,$m_{1})$ opening the same commitment implies to be able to solve DLP)